# Google Map Marker Selection

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have an application which schedules jobs to engineers.  The application uses the Google Maps JavaScript API to display markers showing job locations and the number of jobs at that location – see figure 1.  What I’d like to be able to do is draw a box around a collection of markers and display the sum of all jobs.

How would I draw a box around the markers and then get a list of the selected markers?  All of the jobs are held in an array with a ‘marker’ property used by Google Maps.

Figure 1:

http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/2198/figure1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use polygons for drawing a box and having lat/lng values calculate your markers at box area. See more info about polygons [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Polygons_Overview)

Comment: nice suggestion, but the link is in russian :)

Comment: Sorry :) The correct link is http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Polygons_Overview

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763048/737393).